# Can you get sued for gossiping about an incompetent tech lead if you believe you're saying the truth?

Tags: united-states, defamation, workplace

Can one get sued for gossiping about an incompetent tech lead if you believe you're saying the truth? Let's say a person tells one of his or her coworkers that this tech lead isn't qualified for his job and cannot tell whether a junior developer is a senior developer. Can teh speaker get sued for it?

I think I had to say it, because the guy literally hired junior developers and tried to gaslight me into believing they were senior when they could not complete a landing page after 4 months and returning their terrible work with constructive feedback and identifying several bugs in an interminable circle of mess where they would generate 2 bugs for every fix they made, which is completely absurd.

Would a potential suit have merit, and how would it play out?

Comment: sure. You can get sued pretty much for anything by anyone. The question should focus more on whether a potential sued would have merit and how it may play out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your belief in the truth of a statement is of only limited value in a defamation suit. Saying that a person is incompetent in that person's profession can certainly be defamation, and may even be defamation *per se*, depending on the jurisdiction. If the person sues and the speaker asserts truth as a defense, the speaker may have to **prove** that the statement is true.

Why would one need to say anything at all in such a situation?

Whether such a statement was a factual statement or a statement of opinion would depend very much on the detailed circumstances. But it is at least possible that a suit might be filed and won on this fact pattern.

See [this answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/79461/17500) for more on defamation under US law.

Comment: It is an opinion, so how can you claim it's a statement of fact? It doesn't even pass the first criteria.

Comment: @Sayaman That someone is "an incompetent tech lead" could well be a purported statement of fact.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

What you believe it irrelevant.

For defamation law, what matters is if the statement is an opinion or a statement of fact and if it is *objectively* true or not.

Saying someone is incompetent or not qualified for their job is a statement of fact because competence and qualifications are objective - not a matter of opinion. So, if they sued you for saying that, *you* would need to prove that it was true. For example, by demonstrating that they lacked a required qualification for their job or that they had been formally disciplined by a governing body that had demonstrated “incompetence”.

Saying that you weren’t satisfied with their performance and wouldn’t use them again is not defamatory because that is your opinion, not a statement of fact.

Comment: showing incompetent handling of the consumer interaction might suffice. e.g. "Peter acted incompetent [in the handling of Paula's case]." There doesn't need to be a reprimand, just it being on notice.

Comment: @Trish incompetence is far more broad that that - it means Peter is incapable of doing it, not that he failed in a specific instance.

Comment: note the tiny word *acted* - it makes the general allegation to a description of one instance where they failed.

Comment: State the facts. “Jack hired four developers who couldn’t create a simple website in four months, I let you draw your own conclusions”.

Comment: @gnasher729 replace “couldn’t” with “didn’t” and then you’re stating the facts. Couldn’t implied they were incapable - that’s defamation. Maybe they were just lazy.